# IntelliJ: Inject SQL as language in @Sql annotation

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In a Spring Boot test written in Kotlin, I have a test method which is annotated with `@Sql` like this:

```
@Sql(statements = [
    """insert into employee (created, name)
            values (current_time, 'An, Ny')""",
    """insert into shift (created, progress)
            values (current_time, 80)"""
])
```

These are not recognized by IntelliJ as SQL and have no syntax highlighting (except that of a string). I can add a comment such as `// language=sql` in front of every such string. This, however, is a nuisance (it’s rather like 6 statements in reality).

I’d much prefer a *single* comment or annotation spanning the whole contents of the `@Sql` annotation, however that doesn’t seem to work: IntelliJ proposes to add `@Language("SQL")` in front of the whole annotation but does not recognize the contents as SQL then.

There are settings to configure the injections, even down to parameter level, however that is overwhelming. Is that even the right road, or is there something simpler?

Comment: You should ask the IntelliJ support. I had a similar issue with Kotlin and Spring Data JPA repository methods. There was no autocompletion as well.

Comment: Looks like there is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13233

Comment: This is an interesting issue, however that’s the easy part, multi-line strings. I will update my question to omit that, since it is distracting. Sorry for that.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. The multi-line strings will not work, as Spring (or JDBC) uses them line-by-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3, the issue is partially fixed: Adding a *single* `//language=SQL` comment suffices to highlight all SQL: [IDEA-158709](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158709). The annotation alone is not yet enough: [IDEA-228131](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228131)